# Install tesseract ocr 3 on OSX

Tags: macos, installation, ocr, tesseract-ocr

I am trying to install Tesseract OCR on OSX 10.6...

I have got as far as installing leptonic (by [downloading src](http://www.leptonica.org/download.html) and installing with `./configure; make; sudo make install`) seemingly without any problems - but I don't know how to check.

I also installed Tesseract OCR 3 (from [Google Code](http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-3.00.tar.gz) with `./runautoconf; ./configure; make; sudo make install`) also seemingly without issue - but again I don't know how to check.

When I run `tesseract input.jpg .` I get error...

```
 bash-3.2$ tesseract ~/Desktop/DCIM/101_FUJI/DSCF1043.JPG . 
 Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine with Leptonica
 Error in pixReadStreamJpeg: function not present
 Error in pixReadStream: jpeg: no pix returned
 Error in pixRead: pix not read 
 Error in fopenReadStream: file not found 
 Error in pixRead: image file not found
 Image file ######
 Exif cannot be read!
```

Similar error if I use tiff file as input.

I think I need some libraries - instructions for Ubuntu say to install libjpeg12-dev etc...

Does anyone have details of how to install tesseract on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install macports: see http://www.macports.org/ for downloads and installation instructions.

Update the ports tree:
`sudo port selfupdate`

Install tesseract:
`sudo port install tesseract`

The tesseract port doesn't appear to have a variant that supports jpeg so you would need to install a graphic file converter and image adjustment (brightness, contrast and sharpness) package:
`sudo port install imagemagick`

Convert your jpeg to tiff format, then perform OCR on it with tesseract: `convert input.jpg input.tiff ; tesseract input.tiff ocr-text-ouput -l eng ; rm input.tiff`

The resulting text should be found in the file ocr-text-ouput.txt.

p.s. you can adjust the image a bit for a potentially better OCR experience with convert options like these:
`convert -sharpen 1 -brightness-contrast 3X30 input.jpg input.tiff`

Comment: i had to install 'tesseract-eng' to get around segmentation fault 11.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using homebrew on osx 10.7 and it was as simple as running these two commands:

```
brew install leptonica
brew install tesseract
```

This installed leptonica 1.68 and tesseract 3.01 with their dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Working one command solution for me:

```
sudo brew install tesseract
```

This install tesseract and all dependencies. sudo necessary for some purposes, like jpeg packet linking.